# GCOV: What is the difference between --coverage and --ftest-coverage when building with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, code-coverage, gcov

Trying to get code coverage up and running, and I'm just reading documentation first. I found a few articles that mention building with the `--coverage` flag, while others mention the `--ftest-coverage`.

Both descriptions seem to say they do the same thing, but I'm not certain.

---

Here's two articles:

- http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov
- http://www.osadl.org/Dumping-gcov-data-at-runtime-simple-ex.online-coverage-analysis.0.html

---

What's the difference?

Comment: `--coverage`  is just a abbreviation for the two switches `-ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs`.

Comment: will these flags work with g++ ??

Answer (score 37):

As already stated in the comments `--coverage` is a synonym for other flags related to code coverage depending on the context.

[**3.11 Program Instrumentation Options**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options):

> --coverage
>
> This option is used to compile and link code instrumented for coverage analysis. The option is a synonym for -fprofile-arcs
>   -ftest-coverage (when compiling) and -lgcov (when linking).