# Why two compiler flags needs to be passed for code coverage in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, gcov

I understand two compiler flags: **-ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs** needs to be passed for getting code coverage in GCC. 
My question is, what is the reasoning for having 2 compiler flags for getting coverage. Also, what can we get if we use them independently?.

I tried compiling a c program with only -fprofile-arcs flag. I didnt notice any differences. Was able to generate .gcno .gcda and gcov files

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options) about the options, to see what they actually do?

Comment: Yes, i had gone thru the docs.. But not clear  on why there are 2 flags, when one flag (-fprofile-arcs) serves the purpose

Comment: You don't have to specify two flags. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40993316/671509) which describes `--coverage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options) for `-fprofile-arcs` you will see that the data it generates can be used for two different things depending on other options: `-ftest-coverage` and `-fbranch-probabilities`.

So the `-fprofile-arcs` is to generate code that does instrumentation and saves data. Then you use either `-ftest-coverage` or `-fbranch-probabilities` to specialize the data depending on what analysis you want to perform.

It doesn't say anywhere, but from your experience it seems that GCC defaults to `-ftest-coverage` if none of the specialization flags are provided.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the **Gcov** tool to get code coverage in GCC, refer to [this documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html) which explicitly states:

> When using gcov, you must first compile your program with two special GCC options: ‘-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage’. This tells the compiler to generate additional information needed by gcov (basically a flow graph of the program) and also includes additional code in the object files for generating the extra profiling information needed by gcov.

More precisely, by referring to the [Instrumentation Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html), my understanding about the two flags is the following:

- `-fprofile-arcs` generates the information indicating how many times each branch of your program is taken; in other words, this makes your program generate extra data relative to its execution. The information is stored into *.gcda* files.
- `-ftest-coverage` uses the information produced by `-fprofile-arcs`, and generates *.gcno* files containing control flow information, which can be used by Gcov to produce human readable *.gcov* files. Without the test coverage data obtained with `-fprofile-arcs`, you will not get anything meaningful.

The `-fprofile-arcs` can also be combined with other flags, such as `-fbranch-probabilities` (more information [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)). Typically when using this flag, the compiler performs optimisations to improve branch prediction based on the profiling information contained in the *.gcda* files. `-fprofile-arcs` and `-fbranch-probabilities` are automatically enabled when using `-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use` (this is the standard way for performing **Profile-Guided Optimisation** with GCC).

Hope this helps!

Comment: When `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage` are used for `gcov`, is it obligated to use `g++` with `-O0` (no optimization) flag? This [page](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.ide.userguide%2Ftopic%2Fcoverage_Enabling_Code_Coverage_For_Make_Projects.html) uses `-O0` for this case; but I am not sure what is different if `-O3` is used instead?

Comment: Sorry I found that [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930207/code-coverage-with-optimization) suggest to use `-O0` for coverage test.